# Linker Error in C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker-errors

I am quite new to C++ and I am using a book to get into computergrafics.
I am using Visaul Studio 2013 and Windows 8.
When I try to rebuild the solution, I get the following Errors:

```
1   error LNK2001:unresolved external symbol "_wWinMain@16".    C:\application\gl_application\gl_application\MSVCRT.lib(wcrtexew.obj)   gl_application
2   error LNK1120: unresolved external symbol   C:\application\gl_application\Release\gl_application.exe    1   1   gl_application
```

I took the following code right from the book and all advises a found online didnt help.

application.cpp

```
       #include <glut.h>
        #include "screen_interface.h"
        #include "global_definitions.h"
        #include "palette.h"



        void main_loop( void )
        {

           for( long x=0 ; x<256 ; x++ )
             for( long y=0 ; y<480 ; y++ )
                screen[ y * 640 + x ] = palette[ x ];

            glDrawPixels( x_res, y_res, GL_BGRA_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, screen );
            glFlush();
        }

        void initialise_world( void )
        {
          initialise_platform();
           display_func = 1;
        }

         void display( void )
        {
  switch( display_func )
  {
    case 0  : initialise_world();
              break;
    case 1  : main_loop();
              break;
    default : display_message();
  }
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  glutInit( &argc, argv );
  glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA );
  glutInitWindowSize( x_res, y_res );
  glutCreateWindow( "3D-Grafik Programmierung" );

  glutKeyboardFunc( key_down );
  glutSpecialFunc( special_down );

  glutDisplayFunc( display );
  glutIdleFunc( display );

  glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluOrtho2D( 0, x_res, y_res, 0 );
  glRasterPos2d( 0, 0 );
  glPixelZoom( 1, -1 );

  glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
  glutMainLoop();

  return 0;
}
```

And this Header files:
Screen_interface.h

```
#ifndef SCREEN_INTERFACE_H
#define SCREEN_INTERFACE_H
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <glut.h>

#include "simple_types.h"

const long x_res = 640, y_res = 480;

long display_func = 0;
long message_sx = 0, message_sy = 0;
char message_text[ 10000 ];

long write( long sx, long sy, char *message )
{
  long begin_x = sx;

  for( unsigned long x=0 ; x<strlen( message ) ; x++ )
  {
    if( message[ x ] == '\n' ) {  sx = begin_x;  sy += 12;  continue;  }
    if( message[ x ] == '\t' ) {  sx = ((sx / 64) + 1) * 64;  continue;  }

    glRasterPos2d( sx, sy );

    glutBitmapCharacter( GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_12, message[ x ] );
    sx += glutBitmapWidth( GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_12, message[ x ] );
  }

  return sy;
}

void display_message( void )
{
  GLfloat c[ 4 ];  glGetFloatv( GL_COLOR_CLEAR_VALUE, c );

    glColor3ub( 0, 0, 0 );
    long sy = write( message_sx, message_sy, message_text );

    glColor3ub( 0, 0, 200 );

    if( display_func == 2 )
      write( message_sx, sy, "\n\nDruecken Sie eine beliebige Taste, um das Programm fortzusetzen.\n" );

    if( display_func == 3 )
      write( message_sx, sy, "\n\nDruecken Sie eine beliebige Taste, um das Programm zu beenden.\n" );

  glClearColor( c[ 0 ], c[ 1 ], c[ 2 ], c[ 3 ] );

  glFlush();
}

void set_message( char *message )
{
  unsigned long x;

  long tmp_width = 0, text_width = 0, text_height = 0;
  for( x=0 ; x<strlen( message ) ; x++ )
  {
    if( message[ x ] == '\n' )
    {
      text_height += 12;
      if( tmp_width > text_width ) text_width = tmp_width;
      tmp_width = 0;

      continue;
    }

    if( message[ x ] == '\t' ) {  tmp_width = ((tmp_width / 64) + 1) * 64;  continue;  }

    tmp_width += glutBitmapWidth( GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_12, message[ x ] );
  }
  if( text_width < 288 ) text_width = 288;

  message_sx = (x_res - text_width) / 2;
  message_sy = (y_res - text_height) / 2;

  glClearColor( 1, 1, 1, 1 );
  glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
  sprintf( message_text, "%s", message );
}

void exit_error( char *message )
{
  printf( "\nAbbruch der Programmausfuehrung nach einem schwerwiegenden Fehler:\n\n\n%s\n\n\n", message );
  exit( 1 );
}

void set_exit( char *message, char *user )
{
  char string[ 500 ];
  sprintf( string, "%s\n\n%s\n", user, message );

  exit_error( string );
}

void exit_nofile( char *user, char *filename )
{
  char string[ 500 ];
  sprintf( string, "%s: Fehler beim Oeffnen der Datei '%s'.\n", user, filename );

  exit_error( string );
}

void exit_nomemory( char *user, char *array )
{
  char string[ 500 ];
  sprintf( string, "%s: Fehler waehrend der Reservierung von Arbeitsspeicher fuer das Array '%s'.\n", user, array );

  exit_error( string );
}

#endif
```

global_definitons.h

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_DEFINITIONS
#define GLOBAL_DEFINITIONS

#include "simple_types.h"

pixel_32 *screen = NULL;

void initialise_platform( void )
{
  if
  (
    (screen = new pixel_32[ x_res*y_res ]) == NULL
  )
  exit_error( "initialise_world(): Fehler bei der Reservierung von Arbeitsspeicher.\n" );
}

void destroy_world( void )
{
  if( screen ) delete [] screen;
}

void key_down( uchar key, int mouse_sx, int mouse_sy )
{
  if( display_func == 2 ) {  display_func = 1;  glRasterPos2i( 0, 0 );  return;  }
  else {  destroy_world();  exit( 1 );  }
}

void special_down( int key, int mouse_sx, int mouse_sy )
{
  if( display_func == 2 ) {  display_func = 1;  glRasterPos2i( 0, 0 );  return;  }
  else {  destroy_world();  exit( 1 );  }
}

#endif
```

Simple_Types.h

```
#ifndef SIMPLE_TYPES_H
#define SIMPLE_TYPES_H

#include <math.h>

typedef unsigned char uchar;
typedef unsigned short ushort;
typedef unsigned long ulong;

struct pixel_32
{
  uchar blue, green, red, alpha;

  pixel_32( void ) : red( 0 ), green( 0 ), blue( 0 ), alpha( 0 ) { }
  pixel_32( uchar r, uchar g, uchar b ) : red( r ), green( g ), blue( b ), alpha( 0 ) { }
};

#endif
```

Palette.h

```
#ifndef PALETTE_H
#define PALETTE_H

#include "simple_types.h"
pixel_32 palette[ 256 ] =
{
  pixel_32( 2, 2, 3 ),
  pixel_32( 3, 2, 171 ),
  pixel_32( 3, 171, 3 ),
  pixel_32( 3, 170, 170 ),
  pixel_32( 170, 2, 2 ),
  pixel_32( 170, 2, 171 ),
  pixel_32( 170, 87, 2 ),
  pixel_32( 171, 171, 170 ),
  pixel_32( 87, 87, 86 ),
  pixel_32( 87, 87, 254 ),
  pixel_32( 86, 255, 86 ),
  pixel_32( 87, 254, 255 ),
  pixel_32( 254, 86, 86 ),
  pixel_32( 255, 86, 254 ),
  pixel_32( 255, 254, 86 ),
  pixel_32( 255, 255, 255 ),
  pixel_32( 2, 3, 2 ),
  pixel_32( 23, 23, 22 ),
  pixel_32( 34, 34, 34 ),
  pixel_32( 46, 46, 47 ),
  pixel_32( 59, 58, 59 ),
  pixel_32( 71, 71, 71 ),
  pixel_32( 83, 83, 83 ),
  pixel_32( 99, 99, 98 ),
  pixel_32( 115, 114, 115 ),
  pixel_32( 131, 131, 130 ),
  pixel_32( 146, 147, 146 ),
  pixel_32( 162, 163, 163 ),
  pixel_32( 183, 183, 183 ),
  pixel_32( 203, 202, 203 ),
  pixel_32( 227, 226, 227 ),
  pixel_32( 255, 255, 255 ),
  pixel_32( 3, 3, 254 ),
  pixel_32( 66, 2, 254 ),
  pixel_32( 126, 3, 255 ),
  pixel_32( 191, 2, 255 ),
  pixel_32( 254, 3, 254 ),
  pixel_32( 254, 3, 191 ),
  pixel_32( 255, 2, 126 ),
  pixel_32( 254, 2, 67 ),
  pixel_32( 255, 3, 2 ),
  pixel_32( 255, 66, 2 ),
  pixel_32( 254, 127, 2 ),
  pixel_32( 255, 191, 3 ),
  pixel_32( 254, 255, 3 ),
  pixel_32( 191, 254, 2 ),
  pixel_32( 126, 254, 2 ),
  pixel_32( 66, 254, 2 ),
  pixel_32( 2, 254, 2 ),
  pixel_32( 3, 254, 67 ),
  pixel_32( 3, 255, 127 ),
  pixel_32( 3, 254, 191 ),
  pixel_32( 3, 254, 255 ),
  pixel_32( 2, 191, 254 ),
  pixel_32( 3, 126, 255 ),
  pixel_32( 2, 66, 254 ),
  pixel_32( 127, 127, 254 ),
  pixel_32( 159, 127, 255 ),
  pixel_32( 191, 126, 255 ),
  pixel_32( 222, 127, 255 ),
  pixel_32( 254, 127, 254 ),
  pixel_32( 254, 127, 223 ),
  pixel_32( 255, 127, 190 ),
  pixel_32( 254, 127, 158 ),
  pixel_32( 255, 126, 126 ),
  pixel_32( 254, 159, 126 ),
  pixel_32( 254, 191, 126 ),
  pixel_32( 255, 222, 126 ),
  pixel_32( 255, 254, 126 ),
  pixel_32( 223, 255, 126 ),
  pixel_32( 191, 255, 127 ),
  pixel_32( 158, 254, 127 ),
  pixel_32( 126, 254, 126 ),
  pixel_32( 126, 254, 158 ),
  pixel_32( 127, 254, 191 ),
  pixel_32( 127, 255, 223 ),
  pixel_32( 127, 255, 255 ),
  pixel_32( 126, 222, 255 ),
  pixel_32( 126, 190, 255 ),
  pixel_32( 127, 159, 255 ),
  pixel_32( 183, 182, 255 ),
  pixel_32( 198, 183, 254 ),
  pixel_32( 218, 183, 255 ),
  pixel_32( 234, 183, 255 ),
  pixel_32( 255, 182, 255 ),
  pixel_32( 255, 183, 235 ),
  pixel_32( 254, 182, 218 ),
  pixel_32( 255, 183, 199 ),
  pixel_32( 254, 183, 183 ),
  pixel_32( 254, 198, 182 ),
  pixel_32( 254, 219, 183 ),
  pixel_32( 254, 234, 183 ),
  pixel_32( 255, 255, 182 ),
  pixel_32( 234, 254, 183 ),
  pixel_32( 218, 254, 182 ),
  pixel_32( 198, 255, 182 ),
  pixel_32( 183, 254, 183 ),
  pixel_32( 183, 254, 198 ),
  pixel_32( 183, 255, 218 ),
  pixel_32( 183, 254, 234 ),
  pixel_32( 183, 254, 255 ),
  pixel_32( 183, 234, 254 ),
  pixel_32( 183, 218, 254 ),
  pixel_32( 183, 198, 255 ),
  pixel_32( 3, 2, 114 ),
  pixel_32( 30, 2, 115 ),
  pixel_32( 58, 2, 114 ),
  pixel_32( 86, 3, 114 ),
  pixel_32( 114, 2, 114 ),
  pixel_32( 115, 3, 86 ),
  pixel_32( 115, 3, 58 ),
  pixel_32( 115, 3, 30 ),
  pixel_32( 115, 2, 3 ),
  pixel_32( 114, 30, 2 ),
  pixel_32( 114, 58, 3 ),
  pixel_32( 115, 87, 2 ),
  pixel_32( 114, 115, 2 ),
  pixel_32( 87, 115, 3 ),
  pixel_32( 58, 115, 3 ),
  pixel_32( 31, 114, 2 ),
  pixel_32( 2, 115, 2 ),
  pixel_32( 3, 115, 30 ),
  pixel_32( 3, 114, 58 ),
  pixel_32( 3, 115, 87 ),
  pixel_32( 2, 114, 115 ),
  pixel_32( 2, 87, 115 ),
  pixel_32( 3, 59, 114 ),
  pixel_32( 2, 31, 114 ),
  pixel_32( 59, 58, 114 ),
  pixel_32( 71, 59, 115 ),
  pixel_32( 87, 59, 115 ),
  pixel_32( 98, 58, 115 ),
  pixel_32( 114, 58, 115 ),
  pixel_32( 114, 58, 99 ),
  pixel_32( 114, 59, 87 ),
  pixel_32( 114, 59, 71 ),
  pixel_32( 114, 58, 59 ),
  pixel_32( 114, 70, 58 ),
  pixel_32( 114, 87, 58 ),
  pixel_32( 115, 98, 58 ),
  pixel_32( 114, 115, 58 ),
  pixel_32( 98, 114, 58 ),
  pixel_32( 87, 115, 59 ),
  pixel_32( 71, 115, 59 ),
  pixel_32( 58, 115, 58 ),
  pixel_32( 59, 115, 71 ),
  pixel_32( 58, 114, 86 ),
  pixel_32( 59, 115, 98 ),
  pixel_32( 58, 115, 115 ),
  pixel_32( 59, 98, 115 ),
  pixel_32( 58, 86, 115 ),
  pixel_32( 59, 71, 115 ),
  pixel_32( 82, 83, 115 ),
  pixel_32( 90, 82, 115 ),
  pixel_32( 99, 83, 114 ),
  pixel_32( 107, 83, 114 ),
  pixel_32( 115, 83, 115 ),
  pixel_32( 114, 83, 106 ),
  pixel_32( 115, 82, 98 ),
  pixel_32( 115, 83, 90 ),
  pixel_32( 115, 83, 82 ),
  pixel_32( 114, 90, 83 ),
  pixel_32( 114, 98, 82 ),
  pixel_32( 115, 106, 83 ),
  pixel_32( 115, 115, 82 ),
  pixel_32( 107, 114, 82 ),
  pixel_32( 98, 114, 83 ),
  pixel_32( 91, 115, 83 ),
  pixel_32( 83, 115, 82 ),
  pixel_32( 82, 114, 90 ),
  pixel_32( 82, 115, 99 ),
  pixel_32( 83, 115, 106 ),
  pixel_32( 83, 114, 115 ),
  pixel_32( 82, 107, 114 ),
  pixel_32( 83, 99, 114 ),
  pixel_32( 82, 90, 115 ),
  pixel_32( 3, 2, 66 ),
  pixel_32( 19, 2, 67 ),
  pixel_32( 34, 3, 66 ),
  pixel_32( 50, 2, 67 ),
  pixel_32( 67, 3, 66 ),
  pixel_32( 67, 2, 51 ),
  pixel_32( 66, 3, 34 ),
  pixel_32( 67, 3, 19 ),
  pixel_32( 66, 2, 3 ),
  pixel_32( 67, 19, 2 ),
  pixel_32( 67, 34, 2 ),
  pixel_32( 66, 50, 2 ),
  pixel_32( 67, 67, 2 ),
  pixel_32( 51, 66, 3 ),
  pixel_32( 34, 66, 2 ),
  pixel_32( 18, 66, 2 ),
  pixel_32( 2, 67, 3 ),
  pixel_32( 2, 66, 19 ),
  pixel_32( 3, 67, 35 ),
  pixel_32( 3, 66, 50 ),
  pixel_32( 3, 66, 66 ),
  pixel_32( 2, 50, 66 ),
  pixel_32( 2, 35, 66 ),
  pixel_32( 3, 18, 67 ),
  pixel_32( 35, 34, 66 ),
  pixel_32( 42, 34, 66 ),
  pixel_32( 50, 35, 67 ),
  pixel_32( 59, 34, 66 ),
  pixel_32( 67, 35, 66 ),
  pixel_32( 66, 34, 59 ),
  pixel_32( 66, 35, 51 ),
  pixel_32( 66, 35, 42 ),
  pixel_32( 67, 35, 34 ),
  pixel_32( 67, 42, 34 ),
  pixel_32( 66, 50, 35 ),
  pixel_32( 67, 58, 34 ),
  pixel_32( 67, 67, 35 ),
  pixel_32( 58, 67, 34 ),
  pixel_32( 51, 66, 34 ),
  pixel_32( 43, 67, 35 ),
  pixel_32( 34, 67, 35 ),
  pixel_32( 34, 66, 42 ),
  pixel_32( 35, 67, 50 ),
  pixel_32( 35, 66, 58 ),
  pixel_32( 35, 66, 66 ),
  pixel_32( 35, 58, 67 ),
  pixel_32( 35, 51, 66 ),
  pixel_32( 34, 43, 66 ),
  pixel_32( 47, 46, 66 ),
  pixel_32( 50, 46, 67 ),
  pixel_32( 55, 46, 66 ),
  pixel_32( 63, 46, 66 ),
  pixel_32( 66, 46, 66 ),
  pixel_32( 67, 46, 63 ),
  pixel_32( 66, 46, 54 ),
  pixel_32( 66, 46, 51 ),
  pixel_32( 67, 46, 47 ),
  pixel_32( 66, 51, 47 ),
  pixel_32( 66, 55, 46 ),
  pixel_32( 67, 63, 47 ),
  pixel_32( 66, 66, 47 ),
  pixel_32( 62, 66, 46 ),
  pixel_32( 55, 66, 47 ),
  pixel_32( 50, 66, 47 ),
  pixel_32( 47, 67, 46 ),
  pixel_32( 46, 66, 51 ),
  pixel_32( 47, 67, 55 ),
  pixel_32( 46, 66, 62 ),
  pixel_32( 46, 67, 67 ),
  pixel_32( 46, 63, 67 ),
  pixel_32( 46, 55, 66 ),
  pixel_32( 46, 50, 67 ),
  pixel_32( 0, 0, 0 ),
  pixel_32( 0, 0, 0 ),
  pixel_32( 0, 0, 0 ),
  pixel_32( 0, 0, 0 ),
  pixel_32( 0, 0, 0 ),
  pixel_32( 0, 0, 0 ),
  pixel_32( 0, 0, 0 ),
  pixel_32( 0, 0, 0 )
};

#endif
```

Help would be great, because i tried to fix this for days now.
I have already tried to set the Entrypoint to wWinMainCRTStartup but it didnt help.

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're setting passing `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` instead of console, due to which it expects `int WinMain(HINSTANCE,HINSTANCE,LPSTR,int)` instead of `int main( int argc, char **argv )`. Change it to `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` or change your function to `WinMain` instead of `main`.

The reason subsystem is set to `WINDOWS` is to avoid showing a console window while your GUI/OpenGL program is running. Here's the [relevant MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Changing the Name didnt work, but changing Subsystem to console solved the Problem.